# Differences between v1.8 and 1.10 when disabling gutters on BorderContainer

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I recently changed from 1.8 to 1.10.

When setting `gutters="false"` or `data-dojo-props="gutters:false"` in declarative creation it won`t hide the gutters.

When I set the gutters property in the bordercontainer source to false it still shows the gutters.

All dojo examples refer to `gutters=true`, and all google results refer to older versions.

Edit:

- In 1.8 setting `gutters=false` also removed client borders and padding around bordercontainer.
- In 1.10 it only removes the "gap" between the clients. Is there a setting to get the same results, or should I hack with css / styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually relying on a bug. The visual elements should still be visible, even when using `gutters: false`. This bug has been fixed recently, as you can see in ticket [#17966](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17966) and the [commit](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/commit/adfcd3bd30fae997a8cb8a3891b8c5aa324f1c76) by Bill.

What happened was that the baseClass of the BorderContainer was being overridden when disabling gutters. Because the baseClass was altered, the CSS didn't apply anymore, so the visual elements were removed (that's what you expected).

By disabling the splitters, you no longer get the gutter, as you can see in this demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/HT3PJ/. However, the border around the BorderContainer remains, which makes sense (it is a BorderContainer after all).

---

However, if you're interested in this (buggy) behavior, you can always apply it by yourself by adding a `class="noBorder"` attribute to your BorderContainer and by adding the following CSS:

```css
.noBorder.dijitBorderContainer .dijitBorderContainer-child {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The result will be similar to how it was before, as you can see in this demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/w9ACq/1/

Comment: I often use borderconatiner without splitters, just to have an area occupying all remaining place. In this case it is disturbing, that your solution still won't remove the "padding" inside the container. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: You can set `padding: 0` as well in the CSS. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for v1.10 of dojo:

- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html
- http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/layout/BorderContainer

When false, only resizable panes have a gutter (i.e. draggable splitter) for resizing. Is yours a resizable pane (`splitter:true`)?

I would recommended downloading the source zip of dojo 1.10, unzip to a webserver like tomcat and experimenting with **/dijit/tests/layout/test_BorderContainer.html**

You can access it live here: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/layout/test_BorderContainer.html

Comment: I accepted this, because it contains a link to a test case. Unfortunately - according to my test - 1.10 doesn't produce the same results as 1.8. So this was not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: If your child panes are resizable (splitter:true), gutter will be shown even if you set it false. It would be a good idea to compare your code with the test html as it covers all scenarios.

Comment: My panes are not resizable. As you can see in the demo, there is a gap between the border and content, and a border around all panes. In 1.8 when I set gutters:false, These visual elements are removed too.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent the morning on the same problem. If you want the same behavior you used to have, in 1.10 you want to use dijit.layout.LayoutContainer instead of BorderContainer. Get rid of the gutters=false. LayoutContainer basically seems to be a BorderContainer without the borders.

Comment: And without splitter :( It may be a good idea to replace boredercontainers where I don't need splitters